# Checking if method parameter is subtype fails

Tags: java, class

I have a module that loads some services, then gets some methods and checks if those are valid. One part of this check is making sure that the method parameter is a subtype of the abstract class RealmEventBase. To check that, I use this:

```
if(RealmEventBase.class.isAssignableFrom(m.getParameterTypes()[0])){
   //Valid
}
```

where m is the loaded method. I tried it on a method that should really be valid, yet it always seems to return false. Here is that method:

```
public void OnRealmPlayerInteract(RealmPlayerInteractEvent event){
        //Content removed for clarity
}
```

RealmPlayerInteractEvent does extend RealmEventBase:

```
public class RealmPlayerInteractEvent extends RealmEventBase {
    public RealmPlayerInteractEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event){
       //Stuff
    }
}
```

I am kind of stuck here and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Edit: One thing I thought about was that the method is from another module. Could that be the reason to this? I am kind of new to services and the like.

Comment: Module difference shouldn't make a difference. But if these classes happen to be loaded by different class loaders, surprises of this kind can be expected.

Comment: Are you using a framework? Does that framework use custom class loaders?

Comment: No, I am using the java classloaders/ service loading

Comment: But you could be right about the different class loaders. Some tips for me on how to check that?

Comment: _You are_, yes. But is the "greater code" executed within a framework?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am coding a plugin that is executed by another framework.

Comment: Then I suspect this is a class loader issue. I don't have much experience with this problem, so the only advice I can really given is to either: (1) Read the documentation of your framework to see if there's a fix, or (2) get the `ClassLoader` that loaded the method's parameter type, use it to get _its version_ of `RealmEventBase`, and then perform the is-assignable check with that class.

Comment: With regards to option 1, a suitable fix could be either to find out how to make the two modules be loaded by the same class loader and/or to see if the framework provides its own service-loading mechanism that's more aware of the environment. Beyond that, a [mre] is likely required for some proper help.

Comment: By the way, you can superficially check if this is a class loader issue by testing if `RealmEventBase.class.getClassLoader()` returns the same instance (or maybe parent instance?) as `m.getParameterTypes()[0].getClassLoader()`.

Comment: Thanks I will try this!